# Minecraft Pi - Can't Exit the Game

Tags: operating-systems, minecraft

I just set up a new Raspberry Pi and it came preloaded with Minecraft Pi.

I opened up the game just to see how it works. I then wanted to exit the game but it would only take me back to the title screen.

I'm not familiar at all with this OS so I tried all the windows shortcuts I know: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, nothing worked.  The game was in full screen but there wasn't an "x" to exit the screen. I had to just pull the plug and plug it back in to get back to the desktop... terrible I know, but I seriously don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, here is what I did:

Open TTY1

```
CTRL + ALT + F1
```

Find running processes

```
ps r
```

I found the TTY7 process PID number then enter command where nnnn is the PID number.

```
sudo kill nnnn
```

Go back to GUI (TTY7)

```
ALT + F7
```

Login to your GUI session, this will be a new session.

There may be a better way to do this but this saved me from the pull the plug option.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this thread because I was having the same issue, only I couldn't select or type *anything*, much less Ctrl+Alt+F1.  Esc happened to work for me, taking me back to the main screen, from which I could X out.

Answer (score 0):

With some googling I found like

> When minecraft pi's screen is of an image, you could change that with setting overscan to disable

The first step

```
sudo raspi-config
```

And move to Advanced Setting, move to `overscan` and select Disable.

Overscan is for old TV, I think you are not using old TV so I think it doesn’t affect.

I hope you enjoy MCPi!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, I'm not sure I understand.  How does one change the setting if they can't exit the game?

Comment: You can disable using command “sudo raspi-config” or raspi setting. I think googling is most fast way!

Comment: Thanks TamaTama, but again I don’t understand what you’re suggesting. I have googled the following: “How to exit minecraftPI”, “Can’t exit MinecraftPi”, “How to force quit a program in RasberryPi”, etc. none of which gave me a result that I could use when the screen is on the Minecraft game. How do you use a command when the screen is set on Minecraft and you can’t exit? Is there some keyboard shortcut to get tot the command screen? I apologize but can you please be more detailed in your answer, I’m brand new to this OS. Thanks!